# A way to turn off the design of graduated SE sites (back to beta design)

Tags: feature-request, design

[worldbuilding.SE](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/) is in the process of [graduating](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2767/328). As part of this graduation, it will be receiving its own design.

A first iteration of this design has [already been presented](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2916/328). The response to this design has been largely positive, but some are concerned that it will stand out too much. ([1](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2916/worldbuilding-site-design?cb=1#comment7959_2916), [2](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2916/worldbuilding-site-design?cb=1#comment8425_2916)) And frankly, I can see why, I love the suggested look, but it is very in your face. And yet, it seems very dificult to create a fitting design without standing out too much. I imagine some other sites like rpg.SE and [arquade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/) (to a lesser extent) face the same problem.

Keeping that in mind, would it be an option to provide users with a way to turn off the specific designs for certain SE sites and have it replaced by the standard blue design?

This is what reddit offers, it does lead people to ask if they can't just turn off all custom subreddit styles by default, but this is largely because the mods of a subreddit can freely create their own custom css, a problem Stack Exchange won't face. Still, perhaps an option to turn off all custom designs wouldn't be terrible.

Comment: @ShadowWizard While this question is indeed a duplicate of the one you linked (apologies for that), that question contains no answers since it seems to have been wrongfully closed as a duplicate of a question that asks a similar but ultimately very different question. Is the right action here to try and get the other question to be reopened?

Comment: Agreed, reopened the other one